# Why does this code throw ActivityNotFoundException?

Tags: android

`Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(vc.cellphone));

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setData(lookupUri);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);`

The contact with cell phone number the same as `vc.cellphone` is in the contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if your `Uri` is the problem. What about trying this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", vc.cellphone, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit** - I tried this in the emulator and it works, say, if `vc.cellphone` is `"1234567890"`.

Do you have additional code involved with this intent?

Comment: Thanks, just came to that myself too, but this produces a very odd result: A tableview is shown with 2 items. Both are labelled '2'. Choosing either results in a force-close. 'The process android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly'

Comment: This appears to not work in 2.1 (which is the version I'm targetting) It does work in 2.2. I believe it has something to do with the linking of contacts which behaves differently in 2.2. The tableview I mentioned is labelled 'Contacts'

Comment: Ah, yes. I had been targeting 2.2.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct, and ask a new question since you solved the ActivityNotFoundException. Thankyou.

Comment: OK, now it seems that the 2.1/2.2 thing was a red herring. And actually the problem had to do with multiple contacts with the same cellphone number. Clearing these out solved the problem.